# Header Location code not working--suggestions?

Tags: php, authentication, location

PHP isn't my thing but I need to set up a simple login area--so here I am.  Here's some code I found that seems to work, but won't redirect.

If I change the redirect to an echo it works.  If I change the location to "include" instead it works.  What am I doing wrong in the "location" code?

Am open to suggestions on alternately coding this.  I have a single webpage that if the user enters a password an additional section on the site will appear.  So I have a form on that site submitting to this code and then it's supposed to redirect back with the new section now visible.

Here's my code--

```
<?php

// error reporting
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="foo"; // Mysql username
$password="foo"; // Mysql password
$db_name="foo"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
header("Location: http://www.google.com/"); 

// Register $myusername, $mypassword 
// success
//session_register("myusername");
//session_register("mypassword");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

Comment: Where do you start the session (call session_start())?

Comment: Add `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the top of the script and see if you are getting any error messages.

Comment: OK--I put this piece of code right under the first <?php tag--where would the reporting go?  I know this is probably a REALLY weak question but I don't use PHP at all...this is my introduction I guess.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: OK I instead used ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL); which worked for error reporting.  Indeed am getting a "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [url] in [url] on line 41".  Now to figure out what this means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_register` is deprecated. Hence output already send which you could have seen had error reporting was on. Nothing can be output before `header`

Comment: So if I comment out session_register("myusername"); and session_register("mypassword"); it appears I get the same result.  Where do I need to move these to in the code?  Assume they're needed?

Comment: I modified my code above to reflect the updates.  Still getting "header" sent errors...hmm.

Comment: on line? please mention the line number and what that line is.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your headers have already been sent, which would invalidate the header you're trying to use (although PHP normally will tell you this is a problem).

What could cause your headers to be sent automatically is any normal output outside of your php block (like if your form html exists above this block).

Comment: Trying to understand this.  So I have the form on an index.html page, with a form action that goes to this code (checklogin.php).  This is the error I'm getting, but I don't know where the headers are getting sent with all this stuff commented out.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the issue seemed to be spaces in my code.  Once I removed all the spacing, the problem(s) went away.  Kind of strange--but that's what happened.  Appreciate the help!